# Explanation for a Z-transform solution of a difference equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, dynamical-systems

I am studying Feedback Control of Computing Systems. (specifically using Hellerstein's book, section 3.1.4, page 76)

To solve difference equation Z-Tranform can be applied. In the book there is an example I did not understand how the solution was deduced. Given an integrator: (linear difference equation)

$$ y(k+1) = y(k) + u(k) $$

and the corresponding Z-transform:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{y(k+1)z^{-k}} = zY(z) - zy(0)$$

So (**begin**)

$$ zY(z)-zy(0)=Y(z)+U(z)$$

Solving it: (**end**)

$$ Y(z) = \frac{1}{z-1}[U(z)+zy(0)] $$

What are the intermediate steps from the equation labeled as **begin** through the **end** one?

*Assumption: all signals have a value of $0$ for $k<0$.*

Comment: Algebra-precalculus, really?

Comment: @mrf, yes, I think it is about algebra inserted in the context of dynamical-systems as you can see in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a sign error in your transformed equation. 
The correct equation is
$$z Y(z) - z y(0) = Y(z) + U(z).$$
The rest is algebra, 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
zY(z)-zy(0) &=& Y(z)+U(z) \\
zY(z)-Y(z) &=& U(z) + z y(0) \\
(z-1)Y(z)  &=& U(z) + z y(0) \\
Y(z) &=& \frac{1}{z-1}(U(z)+z  y(0)).
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thank you! I just fixed the equation as you pointed.

Comment: @Lourenco: Glad to help. Cheers!